# Spider Web Chart Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby

I have a table of results and  I would like to present my data using spider web charts. i have looked at the high charts online but can some one come up with an easy explanation on how to embed this in my rails application

Comment: Are you talking about what is also known as a [Radar Chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a high level overview: The Highcharts library you looked at is on the client side. From the ruby side, you'll want to set up some kind of endpoint from which you can fetch data. Once you do that, you can get data using jQuery and then use the Highcharts library in the Javascript side.

Comment: Yes I know where I will be fetching data I have also tried implementing it but nothing appears when I load the page.

Comment: Do you have an example on JSFiddle or something like that where I can take a look at the code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-spider/

Comment: Does it work well when you deploy to a ruby on rails frame work?